# Sorting array of string in a specific format A-Z AA-ZZ

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a array in javascript like this

```
[A,AA,CC,DD,B,C]
```

I want it to be sorted like this

```
[A,B,C,AA,CC,DD]
```

Comment: Where are the changes  ?!

Comment: i want to sort the array in order A-Zthen AA-ZZ and so on.

Comment: sorry my Bad. [A,AA,CC,DD, B,C] to [A,B,C,AA,CC,DD]

Comment: it looks like the cell location of excel.

Comment: Nina you are right i am working with excel files

Comment: @NinaScholz http://stackoverflow.com/q/43708040/7944104

Comment: @WaqasJaved, sorry. can not help.

Answer (score 6):

You can first sort by string length and then alphabetically

```js
var arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'AA', 'CC', 'DD'];

var result = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length || a.localeCompare(b)
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `result` will just the hold reference to arr so its the same thing isn't it?

Comment: Your answer helped me achieve my task. but what the hell is with stackoverflow they dont let me post other questions now.

Answer (score 4):

You could sort first by length of the strings and then by value.

```js
var array = ['A', 'AA', 'B', 'C', 'CC', 'DD'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length || a.localeCompare(b) ;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the length of each element - if it's equal - sort it by the first letter.

```js
var str = ['B','A','C','EEE','CCC','AA','DD','CC'],
    res = str.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.length - b.length || a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0);
    });
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: why only the first letter?

Comment: @MauricePerry Because each of them is equal.

Comment: OK, fair enough

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort array with the pattern you have mentioned then following code will work you.

```
        var temp1 = [];
        var temp2 = [];
        var temp3 = [];
        b=['a','c','bb','cc','aa','b'];
        a= b.sort();
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
        temp = a[i];
        if(temp.length == 1)
        {
        temp1.push(temp);
        }
        if(temp.length == 2)
        {
        temp2.push(temp);
        }
        }

        temp3 = $.merge(temp1 ,temp2);
```

if you are asking about some dynamic function which can sort your string higher than length 2 like [A,B,AA,BB,AAA,BBB] then you have to make it more dynamic.